# Are questions on editing (outside/post the realm of retouching) on topic (or is it graphic design)

Tags: discussion

So I've retouched an image (on topic) and am currently preparing an image for print (using Photoshop) however I'm having trouble after converting an image to the ICC Profile of the ink/paper.

Would a question on how to correct be on topic for photography or would I expect to be migrated to graphic design? I feel this is more a photoshop question compared to photography. My concern is I'm not sure if a graphic designer would tackle the problem the same way as a retoucher.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Absolutely on-topic. We don't consider the process of photographic editing, post-processing, print preparation, and printing as graphic design — rather, they are all part of the art, science, and practice of digital photography.

By direct analogy, the dark room development, fixing, enlarging, and printing of photographic film is all part of the art, science, and practice of film photography.

Comment: That's a really good analogy!

Answer (score 1):

I would say that as long as what is being done is using source material from an image captured by a camera it is on topic here. If source material from a camera is only one of several sources for a work then I would put that squarely in the realm of graphic design.

For example, even if I am compositing multiple images, as long as all of them came from a camera, I think that is photography. But if several images are being used as elements within a larger visual work such as an advertising billboard that has colored backgrounds, text, artwork created using vector graphics, etc. that did not originate from an image captured by a camera then that is graphic design.